# Replace unknown number of rows in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, memory, sparse-matrix

I am running some big simulations where in each iteration a matrix of **unknown row number** gets created. I want to unite all these matrices into one big matrix. Intuitively, the easiest way to do this is setting up an empty matrix before the loop and then appending each result of an iteration with `rbind`. However, this is very inefficient because of memory allocation and I need to have a fast script!

Therefore, I decided to create a sparse results matrix filled with 0s prior to the loop and then replace its rows iteratively with the new matrices. The size of this results matrix is very exaggerated to make sure that I have "enough" rows. The "unused" rows get removed after the loop. An example of my current solution is as follows (this is just dummy code, the real code is more complex):

```
library(Matrix)
#Create empty results matrix
matrix_to_fill<-sparseMatrix(i=integer(0),j=integer(0),x=0,
                             dims=c(100,10))
#Run 10 iterations where a new matrix of unknown size is created
for(i in 1:10){
  #Find first row that is a 0
  first0<-(1:100)[matrix_to_fill[,1]==0][1]
  #Create a new dataframe with random number of rows
  new_matrix<-matrix(rep(1,10*(rpois(1,2)+1)),ncol=10)
  #Replace section of matrix_to_fill starting at first 0-line with new matrix
  matrix_to_fill[first0:(first0+nrow(new_matrix)-1),]<-new_matrix
}
matrix_to_fill<-matrix_to_fill[matrix_to_fill[,1]!=0,]
```

However, again, I am running into a similar problem with memory allocation. Since I do not know what is the number of rows of each of my matrices, I have to **store them first**, calculate their row number and then replace the respective rows in my results matrix.

Is there a way I can replace an **unknown** number of rows in my results table with a new matrix (I do know the starting row and I do know that my table is big enough to "fit" the new matrix)? Or do I have to solve this by creating a "**results list**" of known size prior to the loop instead of a "results matrix" and then fill each new matrix into the list? This would be of course possible, but I'm afraid this would be less efficient...

Thanks!

Comment: Sparse matrices aren't a magic trick. Every time you change the number of non-zero entries in this matrix you'll have to fully reallocate the index and data C arrays that back it. You'd be better off keeping a list of row index / column index / values for each iteration of your simulation and then combining them into a sparse array at the end.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late! Yes, that's what I did now and it turns out to be much faster indeed :)